# fstream to read MSR

Tags: c++, std, intel, fstream, clang++

I am unable to read MSRs (model specific registers) using fstream. Why is this so?

Reading using fopen/fseek/fread works just fine.

Does anyone know why? Below are the privileges for MSRs.

```
# ll /dev/cpu/0/msr
crw------- 1 root root 202, 0 Jan 26 22:29 /dev/cpu/0/msr
```

Comment: The `msr` pseudo-file is a special file that won't support many of the usual operations on the file (e.g., many `fstat` values). Futhermore, regardless of the permissions, reads or writes may fail at any position in the file depending on the semantics of the specific MSR. Evidently the higher level `fstream` functionality relies on some of the unavailable functionality, or tries to buffer some of the file that is unreadable. What is the actual error message you get?

Comment: Do you mean Linux with libstdc++? have you tried with clang's libc++?
I think you should tag your question with the pertinent platform issues to let knowledgeable people in those things get your question.

Comment: The error I see is the bad bit of the fstream is set, there is no further visibility I get apart from that. And I use CLANG.

Answer (score 3):

C++ [buffers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) I/O reads and writes. For example, in a simple GCC application this buffer is set to 8192 bytes. You, of course, have the possibility to alter that size.

As the Wiki page on [setbuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/setbuf) says:

> - GCC 4.6 libstdc++
>
>   With a user-provided buffer, reading from file reads n-1 bytes at a time.
> - Clang++3.0 libc++
>
>   With a user-provided buffer, reading from file reads largest multiples of
>     4096 that fit in the buffer.

This is the reason that a simple `open`, `seek`, `read` on the MSR file from a GCC-compiled program translates to:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/cpu/0/msr", O_RDONLY) = 3
lseek(3, 408, SEEK_SET)                 = 408
read(3, 0x113a0a0, 8191)                = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

Pay attention to the value 8191. The answer behind `EINVAL` is provided by [MSR(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/msr.4.html):

> The  register access is done by opening the file and seeking to the
>   MSR number as offset in the file, and then reading or writing in
>   chunks of 8 bytes.

The easiest fix is to change the size of the buffer. In GCC you can do that like:

```cpp
char buf[8 + 1];
std::ifstream file;
file.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, sizeof(buf));
file.open("/dev/cpu/0/msr", std::ifstream::binary);
```